# My CKEditor and input field do not support Unicode

Tags: php, html, ckeditor

I am using CKEditor, i want to use Unicode and insert in database.

I copy the language and paste in CKEditor or input text and try to insert in database phpmyadmin. But I cannot get the desired output.

How to make my php website Unicode supportive. I am using HTML4 and i need to change my heading.

Here is my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
```

Comment: @PaulCrovella please see the edited question again. my html header are is set correctly ?

Answer (score 0):

I m using `phpmyadmin`, and i change collations and set it to `utf8_general_ci`.

And That solve my problem.